# Include Class in Parent Based on Child Class

Tags: php, oop, laravel, design-patterns, lumen

I have a child controller class that extends a base controller class. In the child I have defined a static namespace string that points to the model class I want to use when calling functions in the base class. Right now, I have to use `call_user_func` to call the function on the correct model class. The code looks something like this:

### Child Class

```
class RolesController extends Controller
{
    const RESOURCE_NAME = 'roles';
    const MODEL = 'Role';
}
```

### Parent Class

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = 'App\\Models\\' . static::MODEL;
    }

    public function getAll(Request $request)
    {
        $objects = call_user_func([$this->model, 'getAll'], [
            Model::GET_OPTION_FORMAT => true
        ]);

        return Response::success([
            static::RESOURCE_NAME => $objects
        ]);
    }
}
```

I can't help but think that this design pattern is incorrect. Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do without having to rely on `call_user_func`? I can not find a similar question as I am struggling to find the words to describe this problem. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Long answer

What makes this cumbersome are the static methods on the model classes. A cleaner approach could look like this:

```
class RolesController extends Controller
{
    const RESOURCE_NAME = 'roles';
    const MODEL = App\Models\Role::class;
}


class Controller extends BaseController
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $modelClass = static::MODEL;
        $this->model = new $modelClass;
    }

    public function getAll(Request $request)
    {
        $objects = $this->model->getAll([
            Model::GET_OPTION_FORMAT => true
        ]);

        return Response::success([
            static::RESOURCE_NAME => $objects
        ]);
    }
}
```

I kept the "model class as constant" approach, but made it an explicit reference to the class.

But now that we are using actual objects, I would recommend to go one step further and instantiate it without the indirection of the class constant:

```
class RolesController extends Controller
{
    const RESOURCE_NAME = 'roles';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = new App\Models\Role();
    }
}


class Controller extends BaseController
{

    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getAll(Request $request)
    {
        $objects = $this->model->getAll([
            Model::GET_OPTION_FORMAT => true
        ]);

        return Response::success([
            static::RESOURCE_NAME => $objects
        ]);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't *need* to change the static method `getAll` to a non-static method. Calling static methods with `$object->method` works fine even in strict mode (just not the other way around).

---

## Short answer

You can also use a variable as class name (not a property, as you tried, the parser can't understand this):

```
$class = $this->model;
$objects = $class::getAll([
    Model::GET_OPTION_FORMAT => true
]);
```

But this only solves your immediate coding problem but not the structural problem.